# Android Service gets destroyed before publishing the result

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I have one Activity(MainActivity) which starts a Service (FirstService) and FirstService starts another Service (SsecondService). The scenario is that MainActivity should wait for result from FirstService, but this will only send a result when it receives something from SecondService.
The problem is that the "onDestroy()" method of FirstService is called and unregisters SecondService before MainActivity gets the final result.

```
>> I/FirstService: On create...
>> I/FirstService: Handling intent...
>> I/SecondService: On create...
>> I/SecondService: On handling intent..
>> I/FirstService: OnDestroy receiver...
>> I/SecondService: Handling result ...
>> I/SecondService: Publishing result ...
```

In my Activity:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_pictures) {
            startAction();   
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void startAction {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "Starting FirstService");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstService.class);
        intent.setAction(FirstService.ACTION_FETCH_PICTURES);
        intent.putExtra(FirstService.EXTRA_ACCOUNT, account);
        this.startService(intent);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "Waiting for onReceive");
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                resultCode = bundle.getInt(FirstService.RESULT);
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case FirstService.RESULT_CODE_OK: [...]
                    }
                    [...]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("MainActivity", "on resume");
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(FirstService.NOTIFICATION));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("MainActivity", "Unregister receiver...");
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
```

My FirstService:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("FirstService", "On create...");           
        registerReceiver(secondReceiver, new IntentFilter(SecondService.NOTIFICATION_SECOND));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("SecondService", "Handling intent...");
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            // .... some more code
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondService.class);
            intent.setAction(SecondService.ACTION_FETCH_VALIDITY);
            intent.putExtra(SecondService.EXTRA_ACCOUNT, accNumber);
            this.startService(intent);
        }
    }

    private void publishResults(int result) {
        Log.i("FirstService", "Publishing result...");
        Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);
        intent.putExtra(RESULT, result);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public BroadcastReceiver secondReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("SecondService", "On receiving result...");
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                result = bundle.getInt(SecondService.RESULT);
                switch (result) {
                    //[....]
                }
                publishResults(result);
            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("SecondService", "OnDestroy receiver...");
        unregisterReceiver(secondReceiver);
    }
```

I am struggling with this for hours now and couldn't find a solution. What am I  doing wrong and what should I do to make it work? Any ideas are well welcomed.
Cheers!

Comment: Please post `onDestroy` of `Activity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have two options:

**Use a static BroadcastReceiver**

You can work with a standalone `BroadcastReceiver`. It has to be registered in the application `Manifest`. Whenever your *SecondService* wants to publish something it broadcasts the results just like before. The receiver could then start another `Service` to process the results.
See also the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#Security)

If you read the link you'll find out that there are disadvantages to using a static `BroadcastReceiver`. So why don't you just skip the receiver and start some (third?) `Service` directly from *SecondService* ?

Which brings us to the second option:

**Implement the first Service as "normal" Service**

Right now, *FirstService* is extending `IntentService`.
If *FirstService* was implemented as a started `Service` then you could make sure it remains alive as long as needed by returning `START_STICKY` from `Service.onStartCommand()`. You'd continue using a dynamic `BroadcastReceiver` or even access the `Service` directly via `onStartcommand()`. And as soon as it is finished your `Service` would unregister the receiver and call `stopSelf()`.

The advantage of an `IntentService` is that it does not do its work on the UI thread. But a started `Service` can use `AsyncTask`, so it can avoid freezing the UI just as well.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the suggestion. I modified the FirstService to be normal Service as you suggested and now the MainActivity receives the final result after everything is executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `IntentService`. If you look at the documentation of IntentService, service starts and do its work in `onHandleIntent` and then finishes. It does not wait for anything. That's why `FirstService` is being destroyed because it has finished its work. Instead, use the Simple `Service` and in handler thread do your work. This is the case your service will continue to run.